# Как убрать белую полоску между виджетами

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlayout, spacing

Почему-то при двух контейнерах появилась белая полоска.

Кто знает, как от нее избавиться?

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(1000, 500)

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.content = QFrame()
        self.left_bar = QFrame()

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.top_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45,45,45);")
        self.left_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45,45,45);")
        self.content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,35,35);")

        self.hbox.addWidget(self.left_bar)
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(40)
        self.left_bar.setMaximumWidth(80)

        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.left_bar)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.content)
        self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox)

        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, но лучше делать как я вам писал в предыдущем вопроск.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(1000, 500)

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.content = QFrame()
        self.left_bar = QFrame()

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout() 
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)                                       # +++

        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        self.top_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45,45,45);")
        self.left_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45,45,45);")
        self.content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,35,35);")

        self.hbox.addWidget(self.left_bar)
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(40)
        self.left_bar.setMaximumWidth(80)

        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.left_bar)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.content)
        self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox)

#        self.setLayout(self.hbox)                                    # ---
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да нет, я от полоски-то избавился, просто не понял причину ее появления, попозже поразмышляю над этим самостоятельно

Comment: @Bitchdragon что не так?

Comment: Да все нормально уже, благодаря вам)